# RxJava2 window,buffer with indicator

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactive-streams

```
[ "start-a", "during-a", "end-a", "start-b", "end-b", "start-c", "something-c", "something-more-c", "end-c"]
```

using String Stream like upper array trying to separate element `start-* ~ end-*` like under result.

```
["start-a", "during-a", "end-a"]
["start-b", "end-b"]
["start-c", "something-c", "end-c"]
```

I'm trying to use window operator

```
    @CheckReturnValue
    @BackpressureSupport(BackpressureKind.ERROR)
    @SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
    public final <U, V> Flowable<Flowable<T>> window(
            Publisher<U> openingIndicator,
            Function<? super U, ? extends Publisher<V>> closingIndicator) {
        return window(openingIndicator, closingIndicator, bufferSize());
    }
```

is there any example for using window operator (openingIndicator, closingIndicator)?

Comment: Maybe one of the custom buffer operators could get you that: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferwhile

Comment: @akamokd thanks solve problem using `FlowableTransformers.bufferUntil()
`